# What kind of battery source do I need?

Tags: batteries, dc-motor

I have 4 12V DC motors each draws 0.65 A max. And a Raspberry Pi which works at 5V and 1A max. I want to do a moving platfrom which at least will hold 5kg of mass.

I have 2x L298N motor driver modules each can support 2 motors and can give 5V output for Raspberry Pi.

So what battery source should I use with 2 or 4 motor connected to this platform?

Comment: Add average current (motors under torque use lots.)  Choose the how long it should run.  Multiply and add safety factor for ageing, etc.  Ah is the answer.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

A LiPO battery was suggested.
These can be very good but a 4S LiPo battery is needed to give 12V or better at end point.

If your motors NEED 12V you need 4S.
A 12V lead acid also probably works.

If much more than 12V is not acceptable then the 4S battery also needs a low dropout voltage regulator.

Ah capacity needed is mean current x hours of operation
eg say 2A x 4 hours = 10 AH or more.

For long life a LA capacity should be >> that with 50% or less (pref much less) DOD (depth of discharge).
A LiPo can be sized for as much as say 80% of rate capacity but charging to less than full V and discharging to say >= 3.2V/cell increases cycle life usefully/.

Answer (score 0):

I'd recommend a 3S LiPo battery pack. These are commonly used in RC vehicles, drones, and robotics.

These batteries are nominally 12V and can provide current far in excess of your application. They're also inexpensive and easy to source.

One consideration is that these batteries are damaged if they're drained too far. You'll need to add a UVLO (undervoltage lockout) and voltmeter to your project to prevent permanent damage.

Comment: A 3S LiPo has a nominal voltage of 10.8V and an end point discharge Voltage of 3 to 3.3V (if not being beaten to death). A 4S battery gives 12V or better at end point. If his motors NEED 12V he needs 4S. A 12V lead acid also probably works. If much more that 12V is not acceptable then the 4S battery also needs a low dropout voltage regulator.